# Test setup error: test tree is empty

Tags: c++, boost, qt-creator

I am trying to build empty boost test project, but i got this error.

> Test setup error: test tree is empty

I am using QT Creator. What does that mean? In boost testing tutorial: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/test/doc/html/tutorials/new-year-resolution.html when you run empty project you get:

> *** No errors detected

My code:
main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#include <mepobject_test.h>
```

mepobject_test.h

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE const_string test
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

// EOF
```

*pro file

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG += qt
LIBS += -L"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" -lboost_unit_test_framework -lboost_system

SOURCES += main.cpp

HEADERS += \
    mepobject_test.h
```

Answer (score 1):

Link with the static library (or use the header-only version). Also, if you plan on using automatic test case registration, better move `BOOST_TEST_MODULE` to your main.cpp file to ensure it satisfies `BOOST_TEST_MAIN` requirements, because it creates an entry point to your test binary.

In your case, likely, the difference between the entry point created by `BOOST_TEST_MODULE` and the one used in the dynamic library is what causing the issue.

See http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Test-tree-is-empty-tp2580070p2580071.html